# In Python, what's the difference between DOWNLOAD_DELAY and time.sleep?

Tags: python, scrapy

As the title said, if I setup `'DOWNLOAD_DELAY'：2`, how's it different from `time.sleep(2)` in each request? [image]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and where do you set it up?You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before editing the question.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is measured in seconds not milliseconds, I believe you meant to say `time.sleep(2)`

Comment: @teclnol `time.sleep` takes time in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: oh yeah thats what I meant to say, oops

Comment: Sorry, typo, sleep(2)

Comment: in custom_settings, setup DOWNLOAD_DELAY

Comment: Are you referring to the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` parameter in settings for `scrapy`? If so, please add the ***Scrapy*** tag to the question.

Comment: Please post code as text, formatted as code, not as a scaled-down screenshot in dark colors on black with a bunch of things randomly underlined or highlighted by your IDE. That's very hard to read, and it means nobody can, e.g., copy things out of it and paste them into a docs search.

Comment: Thank you all guys, this is my first time to ask a question, there's something I wasn't clear, maybe better for next time. Thanks for your warm suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DOWNLOAD_DELAY***, is a way to throttle (in secs) consecutive page downloads from the same website, and the docs can be found [HERE](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)

As for `time.sleep()`, it depends on how you implement it in comparison to `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`. **time.sleep()** suspends all execution until the allotted time has passed, and will have different affects on your code depending on how and ***WHERE*** you are using it. the docs can be found [HERE](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) for `time.sleep`.

If you want to slow down page download, go with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`, if you want to suspend execution of your code at any given time, use `time.sleep`.

Comment: Thank you, PixelEinstein. What if crawler keeps visiting and grabbing data in a same website from page1 to page10 step by step, DOWNLOAD_DELAY is still delay or stop 2 seconds for every different page?

Comment: Yes, if it's the same domain, it will pause for how ever long you set, to download the next page.

Answer (score 1):

[`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) is a Scrapy setting:

> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.

[`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) is a Python library function that can add a delay to your code.

Scrapy can download multiple items at the same time (see [`CONCURRENT_ITEMS`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items) or [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP), for example). The `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` will add a delay between requests to a target and take care of the sleeping logic between requests. Using `time.sleep` would require handling a lot of the logic yourself i.e. while (more requests): make_a_request(...) time.sleep(2 seconds) etc.

Using `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` is preferred because you're letting Scrapy do what it does best. But the meaning of the delay can change depending on other settings (such as `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP`):

> [I]f `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` is non-zero, download delay is enforced per IP, not per domain.